# Why does scanf first return 1 and then 0 when it gets decimal input - but expects integer?

Tags: c, scanf

Why does the following code execute - when a decimal number is entered - at first, but on the second iteration scanf directly returns 0, and the loop breaks?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int num = 1;

    while(num != 0){
        printf("input integer: ");

        if(scanf("%d", &num) == 0)
            break;
        
        printf("out: %d\n", num);      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter, for example, 5.55, it prints 5 (scanf returns 1 and printf executes), however on the next iteration it [scanf] returns 0 and the loop breaks. Why does scanf return 1 in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the format specifier in your format string, `scanf` consumes as much input from input stream as matches for the specified argument type.

For `%s` it reads until it sees a space or end of line.
For `%d` it reads as long as it sees digits.

If you use `%d` and then enter `"5.55"` in `stdin`, `scanf` will only consume the first `'5'` and the remaining `".55"` will stay in the buffer.
On your first call, `scanf` is able to convert input for the first parameter. As a result, it will return `1` and the value `5` is assigned to `num`.

The data in input buffer does not go away between calls to `scanf`.

In your second call you also use `%d` but now, `scanf` sees a `'.'` that does not match the required format. As a result, no input is consumed, no value is converted and the return value is `0`.

This will stay the same for any following call until you consume input in another way.